# how to change tabBar icon color in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

My current tab bar looks as follows:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
-(void)startTabBar{
     self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
     TAB_1  *tab_1 = [[TAB_1 alloc]init];
     TAB_2  *tab_2 = [[TAB_2 alloc]init];
     TAB_3  *tab_3 = [[TAB_3 alloc]init];

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tab_1,tab_2, tab_3, nil];

   self.tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
   self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
}
```

**What i want to do is:**

**Normal tab:** *title of tab should be black as it is but only icon image should be black.* Expected tab should be like :

[image]

**Selected tab:** *title of tab should be red as it is but only icon image should be red.* Expected tab should be like :

[image]

**tab bar color** : *make the whole tabBar color more transparent with same color*

Can anyone help to do this?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18742880/1679187

Comment: @YogeshSuthar That answer is deprecated

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This accomplishes what you're asking for:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setAlpha:0.25];
```

Comment: yes, your are right and it sets transparency to tabbar. Besides, I had to uncomment //[[self tabBarItem] setImage: [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_feed.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]]; in initwithinib method at each tab class

Answer (score 7):

In Swift on iOS8 it would be:

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers here aren't quite what I was looking for. It makes sense if you want a generic change to the color of all tab bar controllers in your app, but realistically, you don't necessarily want to make such a global change (not to mention that it can be difficult to debug and find later). It's better to be more focused, so you want to change the color directly.

As of **iOS 8**, you need to change the `tintColor` property of the tab bar. Hopefully, you're subclassing your `UITabBarController`. If you are, you can set the color in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```