# Change item color in UITabBar iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

My app has a Tab Bar like the follow:

[image]

The Tab Bar must be green and as you can see the icon of the item in Tab Bar are a little hard to see. How I can change the color of the icon in this Tab Bar? I've to use the standard Tab Bar.
Thank you

Comment: see following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526851/how-to-change-tabbar-icon-color-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using of icon you can use icon image by using the following code

```
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

tabBarItem1.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImage.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabBarItem1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselectedImage.png"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabBarItem1.imageInsets= UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
[[self tabBar] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

or this

```
[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{
    UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor greenColor] } forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{
    UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor purpleColor] }     forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Or this

```
[[self tabBar] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

or this

```
    [UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
   [UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor purpleColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

// set tabbar background image
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_bg"]];
// remove shadow image of tabbar
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc]init]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, to change background of UITabbar to some darker colours, instead of green. Just leave the default gray color(Apple masks to gray) for unselected tab. Use below snipped to set selected tab mask color.

**[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];**

This will avoid confusion to end users whether a tab is selected or in unselected state.