# Xamarin Forms TabbedPage Tab Unselected Color

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to change the colour of the **unselected** icons from the TabbedPage.

[image]

I have a custom TabbedRenderer :

```
public class CustomTabbedPage : TabbedRenderer
{
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        if (TabBar == null) return;
        if (TabBar.Items == null) return;

        var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;
        if (tabs != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < TabBar.Items.Length; i++)
            {
                UpdateItem(TabBar.Items[i], tabs.Children[i].Icon);
            }
        }

        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    }

    private void UpdateItem(UITabBarItem item, string icon)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return;
        try
        {
            icon = icon.Replace(".png", " Filled.png");
            if (item == null) return;
            if (item.SelectedImage == null) return;
            if (item.SelectedImage.AccessibilityIdentifier == icon) return;
            item.SelectedImage = UIImage.FromBundle(icon);
            item.SelectedImage.AccessibilityIdentifier = icon;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to set selected icon: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I have managed to change the selected item text colour and the unselected items text colour, but not the icon colours.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526851/how-to-change-tabbar-icon-color-in-ios

Comment: Not useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void UpdateItem(UITabBarItem item, string icon)
{
    if (item == null)
         return;
    try
    {
         string newIcon = icon.Replace(".png", " Filled.png");
         if (item == null) return;
         if (item.SelectedImage == null) return;
         if (item.SelectedImage.AccessibilityIdentifier == icon) return;

         item.Image = UIImage.FromBundle(icon);
         item.Image = item.Image.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIKit.UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);

         item.SelectedImage = UIImage.FromBundle(newIcon);
         item.SelectedImage = item.SelectedImage.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIKit.UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);

         item.SelectedImage.AccessibilityIdentifier = icon;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Unable to set selected icon: " + ex);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unselected icon color:
In the very beginning or your ViewWillAppear event put a line:

```
        TabBar.UnselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.Red; //red is for the yay effect :)
```

Comment: This was added on the latest Xamarin.Forms package. I was running 2.3.3.193 when I post the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Forms 4+ now has **SelectedTabColor** and **UnselectedTabColor** properties on the **TabbedPage** object to easily set directly from shared code, which affects both the text and the icons (but swapping out a different image upon selection would still of course require a custom renderer).

Comment: I can confirm this works. You'd expect the var names to start with Bar as all the other settings such as BarTextColor start with Bar. (Useful for intellisense sakes.)